# abstract class constructors overriding confused

Tags: php, oop, abstract-class

I have this abstract class

```
 abstract class Guitar {

        protected $strings;

        public function __construct($no_of_strings) {
            $this->strings = $no_of_strings;
            echo 'Guitar class constructor is called <br/>';
        }

        abstract function play();
    }
```

And child class,

```
class Box_Guitar extends Guitar {

    public function __construct($no_of_strings) {
        echo 'Box Guitar constructor is called <br/>';
        $this->strings = $strings + 100;
    }

    public function play() {
        echo 'strumming ' . $this->strings;
    }

}
```

Then I initiated the class with,

```
$box_guitar = new Box_Guitar(6);
```

And my out put was

> Box Guitar constructor is called
>
> Guitar class constructor is called
>
> strumming 106

So my question is why parent constructor is called? I didn't use Parent::__construct().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not.

When I run the code you gave above, I get this output:

> Box Guitar constructor is called
>   Notice: Undefined variable: strings in /test/test.php on line 19

Double-check that you're not running an old version of the files or something. Did you forget to save or upload some changes?

---

For the record, once you figure out why you're getting the unexpected behaviour, the right way to write the `Box_Guitar` constructor will probably look something like this:

```
public function __construct($no_of_strings) {
    echo 'Box Guitar constructor is called <br/>';
    parent::__construct($no_of_strings + 100);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @jcsanyi. There was my fault. I have another class called,

```
 class Electric_Guitar extends Guitar {

    public function play() {
        return 'Plug to current : '. $this->strings;
    }
}
```

This has not any constructor. When I invoking objects, I used both of them.

```
$box_guitar = new Box_Guitar(6);
$elec_guitar = new Electric_Guitar(5);
```

So the abstrct constructor was called by elec_guitar object.